# show-word-limit property not working(element.eleme.io)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input, element

I have tried using the show-word-limit property of input element but the count didn't show up.
Here's the code :

```
    <el-input
  type="textarea"
  placeholder="Please input"
  v-model="textarea"
  maxlength="30"
  show-word-limit
>
</el-input>
```

Comment: it works fine here https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/MWyjpzv

Comment: please share  a running example in codepen

Comment: Thanks, but I found the issue.It was the version issue. I upgraded it to latest version and it worked.

Comment: please mention the old and the new versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it was version issue.I upgraded it to the latest version and it worked.
old version: 2.4.0
new version: 2.13.1